# In Antlr4 parser listener if i "return" in a section will it continue to search the child node? if do how do i stop it?

Tags: java, listener, antlr

```
int main(){
    ...
    ParseTree tree = sysYParser.program();
    ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
    MyErrorListener myErrorListener = new MyErrorListener();
    ...
}`
`public class MyErrorListener extends SysYParserBaseListener{
    ...
    @Override public void enterFuncDef(SysYParser.ProgramContext ctx) {return;}
    ...
}
```

will it keep searching the child node of 'FuncDef'?

i've tried code like that but i cant tell whether it searched or not. And sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please use code format for code (3 back ticks )

Comment: A listener performs an LR-traverse of the tree. You can't short circuit the evaluation unless you override the entire traversal method https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/8dcc6526cfb154d688497f31cf1e0904801c6df2/runtime/CSharp/src/Tree/ParseTreeWalker.cs#L22.